# Symfony: Render must be compatible with Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController::render

Tags: symfony, php-7.3

I'm following the tutorial: [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html) and when i change to an AbstractController I get the following error:

```
Compile Error: Declaration of App\Controller\LuckyController::render() must be compatible with Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController::render(string $view, array $parameters = Array, ?Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response $response = NULL): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
```

So I check the original method and add the missing parameters but now i'm getting

```
Compile Error: Declaration of App\Controller\LuckyController::render(string $view, array $parameters = Array, ?Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response $response = NULL) must be compatible with Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController::render(string $view, array $parameters = Array, ?Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response $response = NULL): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
```

here is my code:

```
    <?php
// src/Controller/LuckyController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class LuckyController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/lucky/number")
     */
    public function render(string $view, array $parameters = [], Response $response = null)
    {
        $number = random_int(0, 100);

        return $this->render('lucky/number.html.twig', ['number' => $number]);

    }
}
```

What have i done wrong?

Comment: Better delete question to avoid bad rep.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I was stupid. I should have left the method name as "number"